# Sharepoint Powershell Online - Delete items by date

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Hello Im getting this error when executing this. Can you please help me?

```
foreach($item in $items)
{       
   $created = $item["Created"]
   if ($created -lt $days)
   { 
      Write-Host  "Title - " $item["Title"] "Created - " $item["Created"]

      $test = $item["ID"]
      write-host $test
      $item["ID"].DeleteObject() 
      #$item[].DeleteObject() 
   }
}   

$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

> Method invocation failed because [System.Int32] does not contain a method
>   named 'DeleteObject'.
>   At F:\JoshScript\deletebydate.ps1:46 char:2
>   +     $item["ID"].DeleteObject()
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: have you tried `$item.DeleteObject()`? could you add the line where you create `$items`? what type/object is it?

Comment: Yes i tried that too but it only delete the first item.

Comment: Deleting listitems.Title -  test Created -  4/2/2018 7:05:58 AM
2
The collection was modified. Enumeration operation may not execute.
At F:\JoshScript\deletebydate.ps1:34 char:10
+     foreach($item in $items)
+             ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], InvalidOperationExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException

items are deleted from the list.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you have a look at the [SharePoint PnP PowerShell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell) cmdlets, they make lots of small tasks easier to manage.

Here's the same script using their cmdlets

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url <tenant>.sharepoint.com

$listName = "Shared Documents"
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List $listName -Fields "Title","Created","ID","GUID"
$days = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)

foreach($item in $items) 
{
    $created = $item["Created"]

    Write-Host "Item created on $created"
    if($created -gt $days) 
    {
        continue;
    }

    try
    {
        Remove-PnPListItem -List $listName -Identity $item.Id -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "Unable to delete $($item.Id) in list $listName"
    }
}
```

If you are running Windows 10, then simply run

```
Install-Module -Name SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
```

and it will download and install them from [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline).